# Datamapper and Postgres lost data and error using Sinatra

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sinatra, datamapper

I have a Sinatra app that runs a simple website where the user can confirm attendance to an event and also leave a request with the attendance.

I am using datamapper to save to Postgres.  The model looks like this:

```
require 'data_mapper'
require 'dm-postgres-adapter'

class Guest
    include DataMapper::Resource

    property :id,     Serial
    property :name,  String
    property :attending,    String
    property :others, String
    property :requests, String
```

The issue I am having is that if I the user uses more than 50 characters in the 'request' section then on submission all the data from that entry (all fields from the form) just disappears completely and never gets saved.

I looked at https://moodle2013-14.ua.es/moodle/pluginfile.php/73782/mod_resource/content/2/datamapper.org%20docs/docs/properties.html

and

http://datamapper.org/docs/pitfalls.html

which made me come to the conclusion that datamapper defaults to 50 characters when using a String type.  So I tried the solution they offered which was to amend the requests as such:

```
property :requests, String, :length => 255
```

but having done that I just get the following sinatra error....

DataObjects::DataError at /invitees

ERROR: value too long for type character varying(50)

app.rb looks like this:

```
post '/invitees' do
 Guest.create(name: params[:name], attending: params[:attending],  others: params[:others], requests: params[:requests])
 end
```

Can anyone help???

Comment: I'm guessing you have access to the underlying Postgres database. Are you able to use the postgres console to check the schema has been set up correctly?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you haven't applied the change to the underlying database/table.

If you don't care about blowing away existing data, you can run either `DataMapper.auto_migrate!` (which will recreate everything) or a more-targeted `Guest.auto_migrate!` (which will only recreate the underlying `guests` table).

If you need to preserve existing table data, you'll probably need to execute a more complicated update.  And you'd likely want to do so via `psql`:

```
UPDATE pg_attribute SET atttypmod = 255+4
WHERE attrelid = 'guests'::regclass
AND attname = 'requests';
```